# .net gRPC service without TLS

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

i try to create a gRPC service in .NET 6.

I successfully create a simple service that expose a simple enpoint that return a string.

With the gRPC service , I have the classic web api expose on http and https (http://localhost:51653; https://localhost:71653)

I try with Postman the gRPC call on https port (71563) and the response is OK but if i try to call the gRPC ervice over insicure port (51653) i have this error in Postman:

```
Received RST_STREAM with code 2 triggered by internal client error: Protocol error
```

Now I want to call the gRPC endpoint without the TLS.

Is it possible?

thanks

Comment: Does Postman know that you're trying to get it to make a request without TLS? Just pointing it at a random port isn't enough to say "Don't use TLS for this connection"

Comment: Do a web search for "gRPC tls disable".  here is one answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540899/disabling-certificate-check-in-grpc-tls?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng I don't think that's helpful, as the problem is likely how to disable TLS in postman specifically

Comment: TLS occurs before request is sent and in not inside postman.  When a request is sent the OS intercepts message when HTTPS is used and starts TLS.  When HTTP is used the server must allow both HTTP and HTTPS which has nothing to do with Postman in the client.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Postman, you should see the TLS toggle adjacent to the URL input. Refer here:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/#troubleshooting-certificate-errors

[image]

Comment: All this does is disable TLS on client.  If certificate checking is turned off TLS cannot be used.  That is not the issue.  The issue is to get gRPC server to accept both HTTP and HTTPS (using TLS).